# What is the value of $\angle BMN$?

Tags: geometry, symmetry

[image]

Here $\triangle ABC$ is a isosceles triangle with $AC=BC,\angle C=20^\circ$, $\angle ABM=60^\circ$ and   $\angle BAN=50^\circ$. What is the value of $\angle BMN$? please help me with this problem.

Comment: There is no line from M to N. Are you sure this is what you want us to calculate? And if so, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean $MBN$?

Comment: 75.02492 degrees

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $30^\circ$.

**Proof**: Take a point $F$ on $CB$ such that $BM=BF$. Also, take a point $G$ on $MF$ such that $CM=CG.$ (Note that $G$ is outside of $CBA$)

Since
$$\angle{MFB}=\angle{BMF}=80^\circ,$$
we have
$$\angle{GMC}=\angle{MFB}-\angle{MCF}=60^\circ.$$
Since
$$\angle{GFC}=80^\circ=\angle BAM,$$
$$\angle{GCF}=40^\circ=\angle BMA,$$
$$\begin{align}CF&=CB-BF\\&=CB-BM\\&=CA-CM\\&=MA,\end{align}$$
we know that two triangles $CGF$ and $MBA$ are congruent.

Hence, 
$$\angle CGM=\angle MBA=60^\circ.$$
Hence, we know that a triangle $CGM$ is an equilateral triangle.

Hence, 
$$\begin{align}FN&=BF-BN\\&=BM-BA\\&=CM-FG\\&=GM-FG\\&=FM.\end{align}$$
Since, 
$$\angle NMF=\angle FNM=50^\circ,$$
we have
$$\angle BMN=\angle BMF-\angle NMF=30^\circ.$$

Comment: CF=CA-CM follows from CF=CA - BM

Comment: Is this a Angle-Side-Side(ASS) congruency? Is this allowed?

Comment: @pirsquare: Thanks for the catch. I needed to write a bit more. I edited them.