# Isosceles triangle with concrete angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

While I was going through some problems of the maths olympiad, I came across a problem where concrete angles of a specific triangle were given, which was not typical for a maths olympiad question. Yet I did not manage to solve this problem. It goes as follows:

> In an isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ with base $\overline{AC}$, the angle $\angle CBA$ is $20°$. $D$ is a point on $\overline{AB}$ so $\angle ACD$ is $60°$ and $E$ is a point on $\overline{BC}$ so $\angle EAC$ is $50°$. What is the size of $\angle EDC$?

This is about how far you can get by using basic theorems to solve for angles:

[image: Triangle image]

But I couldn't do much other than notice that $\triangle ACE$ and $\triangle CDB$ are isosceles triangles. My instinct says that the solution might involve cyclic quadrilaterals and the intercept theorem, the triangles $\triangle AEB$ and $\triangle CED$ look like they're similar, but I'm unable to prove that they are.
Thanks!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley's_Adventitious_Angles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the value of $\angle BMN$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635851/what-is-the-value-of-angle-bmn) - found using a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=isosceles+triangle+20+50+60). Note also, that consistent with ACB's comment re: Langley's Adventitious angles, the proposed duplicate question was closed as a duplicate of [Langley's Adventitious Angles](/q/6942).

Comment: @JohnOmielan it does